# Why is my flash drive giving me I/O error after installing bitlocker?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-10, bitlocker

My flash drive keeps responding "I/O Error" and will not read my flash drive after installing bitlocker. I checked Windows built in Device Manager and it appears my drive is online, working, and there is no partitions created. It will not allow me to create any partitions, Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: "The request cannot be preformed because of an I/O device error."

Comment: Unless you reproduced the issue on every Windows Version please use the correct tags related to YOUR system please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might be related to firmware of the SSD not the SSD itself, so update to the newest version of the firmware and restart it. Bitlocker should work after this.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).